# Cortana Reply instead of App Launching

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, cortana

Ok, I've got an application with Cortana support.
I have some command to navigate to specific page. But in some cases I'd like just to provide a reply (text or pronounced by Cortana) instead of launching whole application. Is there any way to do that?

For example, when you're asking Cortana *"What is capital of USA?"*, she just replies you *"Washington"*. I wanna do something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the bottom of this [tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn974228.aspx), it details how to set what she says and shows.

Basically you need to have a background task that runs executes from a voice command and then during the execution you'll need create a `VoiceCommandUserMessage`.

Grab the `VoiceServiceConnection` using the `taskInstance.TriggerDetails`

```
    voiceServiceConnection = 
      VoiceCommandServiceConnection.FromAppServiceTriggerDetails(
        triggerDetails);
```

wait for the voice command to complete

```
    VoiceCommand voiceCommand = await voiceServiceConnection.GetVoiceCommandAsync();
```

then add

```
VoiceCommandUserMessage userMessage = new VoiceCommandUserMessage();
userMessage.DisplayMessage = "Here’s your trip.";
userMessage.SpokenMessage = "Your trip to Vegas is on August 3rd.";
```

wrap it in a response

```
var response = 
  VoiceCommandResponse.CreateResponse(
    userMessage);
```

finally, ask Cortana to display it:

```
await voiceServiceConnection.ReportSuccessAsync(response);
```

Also take a look at the [design guidelines for cortana](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn974233.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding, this is possible only in Windows 10 apps.

https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2015/2-691

Comment: You're right. To do something like that, you have to create *Windows.ApplicationModel.AppService* -> minimum support is Windows 10 (both for mobile and desktop).

Comment: Correct, Windows 10 only.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows applications allow you to iteracte with Cortana at foreground and background. I believe that the background is what you are looking for:

First you need to create a XML file to represet your VCD (Voice Command Definitions). This is the place where you declare the command you want to use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<VoiceCommands xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/voicecommands/1.2">
  <CommandSet xml:lang="en-us" Name="HomeControlCommandSet_en-us">
    <CommandPrefix>HomeControl</CommandPrefix>
    <Example>Control alarm, temperature, light and others</Example>

    <Command Name="CheckTemperature">
      <Example>Check temperature</Example>
      <ListenFor>check [current] temperature</ListenFor>
      <Feedback>Checking temperature</Feedback>
      <VoiceCommandService Target="VoiceCommandService" />
    </Command>

  </CommandSet>
</VoiceCommands>
```

After you need to register the VCD at App.OnLaunched inside App.xaml.cs:

```
protected async override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    ...
    // Install the VCD
    try
    {
        StorageFile vcdStorageFile = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(@"HomeControlCommands.xml");
        await VoiceCommandDefinitionManager.InstallCommandDefinitionsFromStorageFileAsync(vcdStorageFile);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("There was an error registering the Voice Command Definitions", ex);
    }
}
```

After, you need to create a new Windows Runtime Component project and create a class that implements the IBackgroundTask:

```
public sealed class HomeControlVoiceCommandService : IBackgroundTask
{
    private VoiceCommandServiceConnection voiceServiceConnection;
    private BackgroundTaskDeferral serviceDeferral;

    public async void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
    {
        // Create the deferral by requesting it from the task instance
        serviceDeferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();

        AppServiceTriggerDetails triggerDetails = taskInstance.TriggerDetails as AppServiceTriggerDetails;

        if (triggerDetails != null && triggerDetails.Name.Equals("VoiceCommandService"))
        {
            voiceServiceConnection = VoiceCommandServiceConnection.FromAppServiceTriggerDetails(triggerDetails);

            VoiceCommand voiceCommand = await voiceServiceConnection.GetVoiceCommandAsync();

            // Perform the appropriate command depending on the operation defined in VCD
            switch (voiceCommand.CommandName)
            {
                case "CheckTemperature":
                    VoiceCommandUserMessage userMessage = new VoiceCommandUserMessage();
                    userMessage.DisplayMessage = "The current temperature is 23 degrees";
                    userMessage.SpokenMessage = "The current temperature is 23 degrees";

                    VoiceCommandResponse response = VoiceCommandResponse.CreateResponse(userMessage, null);
                    await voiceServiceConnection.ReportSuccessAsync(response);
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        // Once the asynchronous method(s) are done, close the deferral
        serviceDeferral.Complete();
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add this new project as a reference from the main one. Also, you need to register the service inside Package.appxmanifest:

```
<Extensions>
<uap:Extension Category="windows.appService" EntryPoint="CortanaComponent.HomeControlVoiceCommandService">
  <uap:AppService Name="VoiceCommandService" />
</uap:Extension>
</Extensions>
```

This should work!

For a complete guide, you can check out this [post](http://talkitbr.com/2015/08/24/usando-cortana-em-background/)